# How to save traceback's to be used for pdb.post_mortem

Tags: python, pdb, traceback

https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#module-traceback:

> The module uses traceback objects — this is the object type that is stored in the sys.last_traceback variable and returned as the third item from sys.exc_info()

https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_stack:

> traceback.extract_stack(f=None, limit=None)
> Extract the raw traceback from the current stack frame. The return value has the same format as for extract_tb(). The optional f and limit arguments have the same meaning as for print_stack().

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem pdb.post_mortem(traceback=None)

> Enter post-mortem debugging of the given traceback object. If no traceback is given, it uses the one of the exception that is currently being handled (an exception must be being handled if the default is to be used).

yet

```
import traceback
import pdb
try:
    1/0
except Exception:
    t = traceback.extract_stack()
<buncha other stuff>
pdb.post_mortem(t)
```

doesn't work because `traceback.extract_stack()` returns a `StackSummary` object that `pdb` can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `t = sys.exc_info()[2]` instead.